# Ubuntu recognizes HDMI display but not VGA

Tags: display

I do not know if this is a Ubuntu problem or not, but Ubuntu recognizes my display that is connected via HDMI, but my second monitor that is connected via VGA cable is not recognized.

My setup:

- Intel Core i5 x4
- 8GB RAM
- 1TB HDD
- Intel HD Graphics
- 1 HDMI port and one VGA port

What I've tried:

- Trying a different VGA cable
- Going to "Displays" program to fix it,  but it does not see the VGA
  monitor
- Reboot
- Going to BIOS to see if I  needed to enable multi-monitor support

Any help is appreciated, thanks. :)

Edit: When I shut it down and remove the HDMI cord, it boots up fine with VGA. But when I connect HDMI after the boot, it does not recognize it.

Comment: is this a laptop? often when a laptop would hane two external ports HDMI and VGA, but the video card can only support 2 of three at a time.

Comment: It is a desktop (Dell Inspiron 3668, to be exact). Thanks for your response. :)